# Extract substring using two delimiters and NO REGEX

Tags: perl, split, substring

I have a function whose aim is to extract a substring found between two delimiters. I would use regex but in this case I have explicit instructions not to use them.

I had a simpler and more elegant solution which was just one line but I cannot for the life of me remember or find it.

```
sub findBetween {

my ($theString,$delimiter1,$delimiter2) = (@_);
my $tmp = substr($theString, index($theString,$delimiter1)+length($delimiter1));
$tmp = substr($tmp, 0, index($tmp,$delimiter2));
return $tmp;}
```

Thank you for taking a look at this issue, I am aware it is very basic and somewhat redundant. What I need is a simpler solution involving perl basic functions and no regex.

Comment: It would be interesting to hear why you cannot use a regex?

Comment: The reasons I have been provided:
- The scripts these functions are in are parsing very large files 
- This function is used extremely often
- Using a function without regex is measureably faster in this case

Comment: I am not sure about `substr` + 2 times `index` being faster than a regex match operation. You  could do a benchmark to check that it really is faster

Comment: That was exactly my thought too; the benchmarks did prove to be correct. I don't remember the specifics but while it was not miles faster it was at least noticeably faster (we're talking seconds out of a minute). This said I do feel in this situation that correlation does not imply causation, from my discussions with software engineer buddies they are all surprised with this outcome.

Comment: I ran a [benchmark](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/187684/33560) and it seems that `substr` + `index` is usually faster than a regex match, but not for all cases. If you like to improve the speed even further, you could also consider implementing the `findBetween()` in C.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two `index()` calls to locate both delimiters and use indexes to extract string between them,

```
sub findBetween {

    my ($theString,$delimiter1,$delimiter2) = @_;

    my $i1 = index($theString, $delimiter1, 0) + length($delimiter1);
    my $i2 = index($theString, $delimiter2, $i1);

    return substr($theString, $i1, $i2-$i1);
}

print findBetween("111--2222~~333", "--", "~~"), "\n";
```

output

```
2222
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use [`index`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index.html)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = "hello my world";
my $substr = "my";
    if (index($string, $substr) != -1) {
        print "$substr found in $string";
  }
```

Extract from [perldoc](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index.html)

> • index STR,SUBSTR,POSITION
>
> • index STR,SUBSTR
>
> > The index function searches for one string within another, but without the wildcard-like behavior of a full regular-expression pattern match. It returns the position of the first occurrence of SUBSTR in STR at or after POSITION. If POSITION is omitted, starts searching from the beginning of the string. POSITION before the beginning of the string or after its end is treated as if it were the beginning or the end, respectively. POSITION and the return value are based at zero. If the substring is not found, index returns -1.

Comment: I see what you are saying; the issue here is I want it to return the substring however I do not know the substring, i know the delimiters. 

So in your exemple it would be:
"hello " and " world"

Comment: then simply loop index to find the delimiters and print the substring based on position.

Comment: Yes I see how that would work; however I remember finding a solution that was only a line with two functions which worked perfectly.

Comment: must have been a regex or perhaps sed.

Comment: I see what you mean, and had I not seen this solution I would be inclined to agree wholeheartedly with you. I'll definitely update if and when I do find it.